# C-e to end of Headline

Tags: org-mode, motion

Something has changed for me, since I upgraded to newer org-mode

If I have this

```
* foo
** bar...
** baz...
```

If I put point on "**", then hit C-e to go to the end of line, it only moves point to after "r", while I expect it to move it to the end of the line.

Is there an easy way to get back this behavior?;)

Comment: The `r` *is* the end of the line (heading), is it not?  Surely the `...` is representing the elided text *underneath* that heading.

Comment: Well, if I hit enter after C-e, it expands the headline. I don't want that. I want a new line. If I wanted to expand the headline, I would've hit tab

Comment: I guess you must have been using Emacs 25 previously.  I can see that `org-end-of-line` changed in 26.1 to mean "Go to the end of the line, but before ellipsis, if any."   In Emacs 25 it would put the cursor after the `...` meaning at the *very end* of the collapsed section (i.e. *not* just the end of the heading).  Is that what you want?

Comment: It looks pretty hard-coded, but you could try `(with-eval-after-load "org" (define-key org-mode-map "\C-e" nil))` to remove the org binding and fall back to the default (which is most likely `move-end-of-line`).

Comment: Sorry, that didn't work;) It still does not go to the very end of the collapsed section after evaluating that.

Comment: Oh I see... in Emacs 27 they've added a remapping to the keymap which causes my suggested unbinding to then fall back to the exact same thing which we'd unbound.  That seems excessive, and possibly a hint that the org devs feel there's a good reason for you *not* to do this.  To tackle both things you actually need: `(with-eval-after-load "org" (define-key org-mode-map "\C-e" nil) (define-key org-mode-map [remap move-end-of-line] nil))`

Comment: Hehe, thanks a lot; now it's perfect again;) You can add this as a solution;)

Comment: If you don't want to remap something, you can also hit `M-e` two times and the cursor goes after the `...`.

Comment: I'll rather save energy;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remove the `org-move-end-of-line` bindings for <kbd>C-e</kbd> like so:

```el
(with-eval-after-load "org"
  (define-key org-mode-map "\C-e" nil)
  (define-key org-mode-map [remap move-end-of-line] nil))
```

Emacs 26.1 introduced the `org-move-end-of-line` behaviour change whereby it stops before the elided `...` of a collapsed section; but note that prior to that change org did still have its own `org-move-end-of-line`, and so the code above (which should cause Emacs to simply call the default `move-end-of-line` command instead of org's version) is still likely to behave differently in some ways.

The current version of the function doesn't provide an option for the behaviour you want, but you could potentially add an older (or modified) version of `org-move-end-of-line` to your own config.